# Databricks Sql Connector Python - Cancel inflight query

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I'm attempting to cancel a running query in a separate thread using the `cursor.cancel()` function as mentioned in [Databricks Docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html#cancel-method). However, I'm encountering the following error, and the query seems to cancel inconsistently. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.

```
Error during request to server: INVALID_STATE_TRANSITION: Command xxxxxx state cannot be updated.
```